# Build Standalone Expo .apk with Turtle CLI "Bundle was not loaded from the packager"

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to generate apk from a Expo project without eject and using my own CI following this [tutorial](https://www.robincussol.com/build-standalone-expo-apk-ipa-with-turtle-cli/)

I generated my standalone APK without run expo server and everything works fine: the apk installation, the APIs Call, the button actions etc. The only 'detail' is that the static images were not loaded and this warning appears when app launches `Bundle was not loaded from the package`

I added the **assetBundlePatterns** line in my app.json like recommended in [React Native Documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/offline-support/#bundle-your-assets-inside-your-standalone-binary)

Theres my app.json

```
 {
  "expo": {
    "name": "My App",
    "description": "My App",
    "slug": "my app",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "./assets/images/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "br.com.myapp",
      "buildNumber": "001"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "br.com.myapp"
    }
  }
}
```

and there's how I load images:

**Homepage.js**
....

```
class Homepage extends Component {
render() {
  return(
 <Image style={[{width:width, height:380}]} source={banner1}/>
);
}
}
const banner1 = require('../assets/images/banner.png')
```

I don't know why the static images were not loaded and How to fix it

Comment: I have a similar issue, have you found a solution/workaround? :)

Comment: @PedroA I removed all Expo Libraries from project and Ejected Expo :) Now, I'm free from expo constraints hehehe

Comment: Hmmm I see, thank you!!